# Method to fill array with prime numbers in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, primes

Write a method that,when given an integer value,checks whether the value is a prime number or not.
Using your previous answer, write code that fills an array with the first 20 prime numbers.

I have solved the first part and have a method called checkPrime(int n) and it returns true or false. I am confused in the second part which loops should I use, I was trying to do something like this but got stuck :

```
public static void fillArray() {
    int[] arr = new arr[20];
    n = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (checkPrime(n) == True) {
            arr[i] = n;
            n++;
        } else {
            n++;
        }
}
```

Here, if the number isnt prime n is being incremented but we arent checking if its prime again.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a nested while loop inside. while(!checkPrime) { n++ } and then after add it to the array.

Comment: Also there is no need to do checkPrime(n) == true. Just do checkPrime(n)

Comment: No prob. Good luck

Comment: Better to call your `checkPrime()` method, `isPrime()`.  That is more in keeping with the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @stephen Docy thanks for the edit !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one variable to hold your position in your output array, and another to increment in your loop to test for primality. And, I would return the `int[]` I built. And pass the number of desired elements into the function. When it is prime, add it to the array. Loop until your array index equals your array length. And it's `int[]` (not `arr[]`). Like,

```
public static int[] fillArray(int count) {
    int[] arr = new int[count];
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 1; n < arr.length; i++) {
        if (checkPrime(i)) {
            arr[n] = i;
            n++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**or**, if you're using Java 8+, you could use an `IntStream` with a `filter` and a `limit`. Like,

```
public static int[] fillArray(int count) {
    return IntStream.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .filter(x -> checkPrime(x))
            .limit(count).toArray();
}
```

Comment: From what I understand you are checking for prime numbers only till the value of the length of array. But that wouldn't necessarily fill the array with the first n(20 here) numbers. Will it ?

Comment: @noogler It will as long as `count` is `20`. Because the loop invariant is against `n` (not `i`).

Comment: Ah okay, my bad. Thanks I did not know we can have two different variables in loop. Always thought we have to make the loop on i. Thanks !

Answer (score -2):

just do it like these the i will not increes until the loop find a prine number and add it to the array

```
public static void fillArray(){
int[] arr = new arr[20];
int n -1;
for ( int i = 0; i < 20; ){
if (checkPrime(n) == True){
arr[i] = n;
n++;
i++;
}else {
n++}
}
```